# How to reproduce error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress?

Tags: oracle, initialization

I have an application on java that uses hibernate to write in oracle db.
Sometimes I found in log error 01033. But I cannot reproduce it.
I have already restarted server, oracleXE service, killed task, killed tns listener.
But I have receive only:

```
 ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of 
 SID given in connect descriptor
```

What need to do with Oracle server to receive error ORA-01033?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to force `ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress.` you should be able to do this as follows

1. log on as sys and shutdown the database
2. run `startup mount` (again as sys)

now all clients should get that error message. note: the listener should be up.

as sys:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  630501376 bytes
Fixed Size          2230992 bytes
Variable Size          43934256 bytes
Database Buffers      281018368 bytes
Redo Buffers        3317760 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL>
```

then as a client:

```
M:\>sqlplus test/test@oracle11203

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Feb 26 15:18:45 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name:
```

to clear the error, just run

```
alter database open
```

as sys. Now all clients can login as usual.

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress.
>
> Cause: An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up
>   or shutdown.
>
> Action: Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation
>
> The first step in resolving the “The ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization
>   or shutdown in progress” error is to check and see if the target
>   database is indeed in the middle of startup or shutdown.   The
>   ORA-01033 error also happens when the database is not open.  After you
>   create the control file issue the command:   “alter database open”
>
> That should stop the ORA-01033 error and make the database available
>   for general use.    The “ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown
>   in progress.” error can also happen when Oracle is attempting startup
>   or shutdown and is "hanging" on a resource such as a failed disk,
>   writing to redo, etc.

Source : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01033_initialization_shutdown_progress.htm

Comment: So trying to restart database, and sending queries during this phase should work. May be you can try to Startup your database in nomount mode, then mount and then open. And try to send queries in every phase. I believe you can reproduce this error when database is up and mounted but not opened yet.

Comment: @tbone I shared reason and solution of ORA-01033 beacuse to reproduce an error you have to know the exact reason of the error, or the steps that causes the error. In our case exact reason should help us to reproduce this error.